# Angular2 Reactive forms - Set default value for form fields with dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

How can I set the default value for all forms fields in angular 2 reactive forms?

Here is the [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/GKguMzZbr0kzrraPP73f?p=preview) to reproduce the issue

Below code does not update dropdown values as it has an object associated with it.

Note: Here I need to set the default value for all form fields with the response received from Backend API.

Component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(myForm.value, myForm.valid)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Country:</label>
        <select formControlName="country">
          <option *ngFor="let country of masterCountries" [ngValue]="country">{{country.countryName}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name">
      <small [hidden]="myForm.controls.name.valid || (myForm.controls.name.pristine && !submitted)" class="text-danger">
            Name is required (minimum 5 characters).
          </small>
      <!--<pre class="margin-20">{{ myForm.controls.name.errors | json }}</pre>-->
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    <div class="margin-20">
      <div>myForm details:-</div>
      <pre>Is myForm valid?: <br>{{myForm.valid | json}}</pre>
      <pre>Is myForm submitted?: <br>{{submitted | json}}</pre>
      <pre>myForm value: <br>{{myForm.value | json}}</pre>
    </div>
```

Component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    public myForm: FormGroup;
    public masterCountries: any[] = [{"countryCode":"AF","countryName":"Afghanistan"},{"countryCode":"AL","countryName":"Albania"},{"countryCode":"DZ","countryName":"Algeria"},{"countryCode":"AS","countryName":"American Samoa"},{"countryCode":"AD","countryName":"Andorra"}];

    // Sample response received from backend api
    public CountryResponse = {country: {"countryCode":"AF","countryName":"Afghanistan"}, name: 'test123'};
    constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {

        // the short way
        this.myForm = this._fb.group({
            country: [''],
            name: ['', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(5)]],
        });


        (<FormGroup>this.myForm)
            .setValue(this.CountryResponse, {onlySelf: true});


    }


    save(model: User, isValid: boolean) {
        this.submitted = true;
        console.log(model, isValid);
    }
}
```

Let me know if there is any other way to set the whole form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 2 - bind object to dropdown and select value based on an event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39105905/angular-2-bind-object-to-dropdown-and-select-value-based-on-an-event)

Comment: And also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39745629/angular2-two-way-binding-to-select-option-not-updating

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I need to update all form fields with the sample response received from backend. updated my question to reflect the same

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just change this:

```
 (<FormGroup>this.myForm)
            .setValue(this.CountryResponse, {onlySelf: true});
```

Into this:

```
const selectedCountry = this.masterCountries.find(country => country.countryCode === this.CountryResponse.country.countryCode)
this.CountryResponse.country = selectedCountry;
(<FormGroup>this.myForm)
            .setValue(this.CountryResponse, {onlySelf: true});
```

As said before you need to pass the exact same reference of the object

Comment: patchValue is more appropriate

Answer (score 50):

I know this is an old question, but if anyone looks for it, there is now a better way to set value in the whole form, with **[PatchValue](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#populate-the-form-model-with-setvalue-and-patchvalue)**:

```
this.myForm.patchValue({
   country: this.CountryResponse,
   name: 'Any Name'
});
```

this also allows partial, so you would still be able to do something like:

```
this.myForm.patchValue({ country: this.CountryResponse });
```

or you can set the value into a single control:

```
this.myForm.get('country').setValue(this.CountryResponse);
```

Answer (score 17):

When you declare the form control or initialise pass the default value as a parameter

```
  MyFormControl: FormControl = new FormControl('Default value');
```

Comment: cleanest way to do this

Comment: I think this is a cleaner way to achieve. It worked for me thanks

Comment: What if I dont want to show default value in HTML view?

Answer (score 10):

Your code does not work because although your `this.selectedCountry` appears to have the same fields' values with one of the elements of `this.masterCountries`, they are **not the same object**. That makes `select.value === option.value` comparison always returns `false`.

It's simple to make it works, just change your `setValue` function to as follow:

```
(<FormControl>this.form.controls['country'])
            .setValue(this.masterCountries[0], { onlySelf: true });
```

Or you can just set it when creating the `FormGroup`:

```
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
        country: [this.masterCountries[0]],
        name: ['', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(5)]],
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes it works if i use the masterCountries to set the value. But I need to set the whole form with the response received from backend. Updated my plnkr with thsi scenario. https://plnkr.co/edit/GKguMzZbr0kzrraPP73f?p=preview